# Как в url добавить переменную категории и id?

Tags: .htaccess

Через `.htaccess` нужно сделать так, что бы адресс был ввида `site.ru/категория/ид`
Сейчас переход вида `site.ru/file.php?id=$row['id']/` Переменная категории `$rowcat['name']`

Как через .htaccess настроить, чтобы url был вида `site.ru/$rowcat['name']/$row['id']/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Впервые вижу элемент массива в значении переменной URL. :-) Мне сложно понять эти конструкции. Видимо, уже применены какие-то правила mod_rewrite.

Может быть сейчас `file.php?id=1&cat=2`, например? Или всё же `file.php?id=1/2` ? А нужно, как я поняла вообще `site.ru/2/1/` или всё же `site.ru/2/1` ?

Научите, как такой простой вопрос превратить в такой сложный?! :-)

upd

Добавьте в .htaccess строки

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ file.php?cat=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ file.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: :)
Пускай, url будет file.php?id=1&cat=2, все равно применяется переменная лишь id. Насчет последнего слэша, то нужно, чтобы работало оба варианта...

Comment: Если применяется лишь id, зачем тогда переменная категории? Для красоты? :)

Comment: Да, для красоты :)